# Comparison between passing an object with a handleEvent property and traditional callback function in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener, object-literal, interface-implementation

I read an article [(link)](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent) which explains that the seconde argument of `addEventListener` can be a function or an object implementing `handleEvent` method.

In the **But wait there’s more** section of this article, it says using `handleEvent` can avoid removing and re-attach the event handler. But I'm wondering if this is a better way than repeatedly 'add' and 'remove'? In terms of tidy code, performance or whatever?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

Using an object as a listener:

```
var listener = 
    {
    handleEvent: function (evt) {
 
        this === listener; // true
 
        // and evt === classic event object
    }
};


document.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

has the following advantages:

- It separates the interface from the implementation
- It helps avoid circular references to DOM objects
- It isolates `this` from the Event object

> Specification authors should not define callback interfaces that have only a single operation, unless required to describe the requirements of existing APIs. Instead, a callback function should be used.
>
> The definition of EventListener as a callback interface is an example of an existing API that needs to allow user objects with a given property (in this case “handleEvent”) to be considered to implement the interface. For new APIs, and those for which there are no compatibility concerns, using a callback function will allow only a Function object (in the ECMAScript language binding).

**References**

- [An alternative way to addEventListener - Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/an-alternative-way-to-addeventlistener)
- [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Events Specification: Interface EventListener](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20110531/#events-EventTarget)
- [W3C DOM Level 2 version 1.0 - Java API: Interface EventListener](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/events/EventListener.html#handleEvent_org.w3c.dom.events.Event_)
- [Web IDL: Callback Interfaces](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#ref-for-dfn-callback-interface-3)
- [WebIDL-1: Implementation Report - All Results](https://www.w3.org/WebPlatform/WG/implementations/webidl-1/report/all.html)